# How to use superduper to set up a new computer but only copying user files

Tags: macos, restore, superduper

I have a Mac Mini that I am preparing to sell, and I already have my replacement Mac Mini in my possession.

I have fully backed up Mac Mini 1 using SuperDuper onto an external hard drive.

Mac Mini 2 is sitting around waiting to be unboxed.

I know it is possible to fully restore Mac Mini 2 to Mac Mini 1's state using SuperDuper, but for various reasons I would rather just set up MacMini 2 as if it were a new machine, and then, after I have the user set up, copy the user data from the external hard drive over to Mac Mini 2.

Can this be done?

How can I do this?

If you couldn't tell from my explanation, I'm sort of new at this, your patience is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up your new mini, you will be given the opportunity to copy all your user data from another machine. It's painless and quite simple.